# Appcelerator studio hangsHangs on startup (first run)

Tags: appcelerator-studio

I'm having a hard time running Appcelerator Studio on Mac OS Sierra for the first time.

After entering my credentials and clicking login, I get the following screen and the application never starts.

[image: screen]

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue on my brand new MBP that I upgraded to OSX Sierra before installing studio. Also I occasionally use my windows machine with [appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) and this also avoid the studio prompts. Using the [Appcelerator CLI commands](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/API_Builder_CLI-section-src-49159313_APIBuilderCLI-CLIcommands) to manually logout/login typically resolves the issue in seconds.

This worked for me:

1. Force Appcelerator Studio to quit.
2. Open Terminal (Launchpad > Other > Terminal)
3. Logout of Appcelerator at prompt enter: `appc logout`
4. Login to Appcelerator at prompt enter: `appc login` (follow prompts)
5. Open Appcelerator Studio

Answer (score 2):

I once got the hint from Appcelerator Support to use `appc logout -D` in the CLI to log out and then login again using `appc login` to solve this problem. This helps for me when this problem occurs.